# Do I need to explicitly save a modified domain object within a spring transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

If I have a transaction as follows where my domain object is mapped as Cascade.ALL using Hibernate:

```
@Transactional
public void transactionAllMethod(Domain domain) {
     domain.addItemToCollection(new Item);
     //Do I need to call domain.saveOrUpdate() here, or will changes to the domain be flushed
     //automatically at the end of the transaction with FLUSHMODE.AUTO?

     Domain domain2 = new Domain();
     //set some fields here

     //Do I need to save my second domain as it is new, or again will things be
     //automatically persisted during dirtychecking at the end of the transaction?
}
```

If I don't need to explicitly saving in either case, where should I be doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to merge any changes to an existing entity, and save the new one.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.merge(domain);
session.save(domain2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If domain is new you will need to save it and if it's detached you will need to call update to reattach it to the session. Hibernate will only dirty check entities which are attached to the current session.

In the case of domain2 you need to call save to ensure that it is dirty checked.